# Computer with two DNS names. "There are currently no logon servers to service the logon request"

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a temporary situation where there is a remote office in the US connected via a vpn to servers in the UK (domain controllers, file servers, etc)

To try to improve things in the remote office I recently set up one of their computers as a local file server.  To make it seem more appropriate I gave the computer a second DNS name so that instead of reaching it by `\\computername` they can reach it by `\\localfileservername` (the actual names are changed for this SF question)

This worked fine for a while.  But now, when I try to access `\\localfileservername` I get "There are currently no logon servers available to service this logon request" but if I access it via `\\computername` it works fine.

Oddly I also get the error when I access it via `\\ipaddress`

Also to improve things in this temporary arrangement I have a number of servers set up in the hosts files of the machines at the remote office,  and I added the name of this impromptu file server to the hosts file after I set it up (as well as in the DNS server).

So my question is, is having two names for the computer causing this problem?  And is there anything I can do or check to improve this situation or get rid of this error.

Incidentally I'm finding this error occurring generally more frequently, in situations where the domain controllers *are* reachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lanman strict name checking can block you.

Its a security added in the OS that make the server listen only to its own DNS name (no alias)

Do the following to disable it:

In your registry editor, go to

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters.
Right-click and add the DWORD entry “DisableStrictNameChecking” and set the value to 1.

Right-click again and add the DWORD entry “DnsOnWire” with a value of 1.

Restart the server.